# Android BackupManager and my app db: best approaches

Tags: android, database, android-backup-service

I'd like to use the `BackupManager` to back a DB for my app. The documentation talks about `BackupAgent` and `BackupAgentHelper`, and it states that you want to use `BackupAgent` if you have a DB.

On the other hand, the `BackupAgentHelper` has a neat `FileBackupHelper` that makes things quite easy.

My questions:

1) Is it possible to use `FileBackupHelper` to backup the .sqlite file in /data/data/<myapp>/databases?

2) if not, is it possible to use the `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s methods inside `onBackup()` and `onRestore()` (onCreate/onUpgrade to backup/restore)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android backup/restore: how to backup an internal database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282936/android-backup-restore-how-to-backup-an-internal-database)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.  When you extend **BackupAgentHelper** and implement its **onCreate()**, you can do something like this in there:

```
addHelper(STATS_BACKUP_KEY, new DbBackupHelper(this, "my_db_name"));
```

And your DbBackupHelper class can look like this:

```
public class DbBackupHelper extends FileBackupHelper {

    public DbBackupHelper(Context ctx, String dbName) {
        super(ctx, "../databases/" + dbName);
    }
}
```

For a full example, check out the Andlytics project on GitHub: [AndlyticsProject](https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics).