# Android BackupRestore example not working on Android 2.3 Nexus One

Tags: android, backup, android-backup-service

I've created a sample project using `BackupRestore`. I went to register for a key at Android Backup Service. I got the following:

> Your key is: 
>   AEdPqrEAAAAIW4p30C1GTNjzBOqWrb0clI7_OCWxm3ddIgkKhw 
>   This key is good for the app with the package name:
>
> com.example.android.backuprestore
>   Provide this key in your AndroidManifest.xml file with the following  element,
>   placed inside the <application> element:
>
> <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
>       android:value="AEdPqrEAAAAIW4p30C1GTNjzBOqWrb0clI7_OCWxm3ddIgkKhw" />

When I launch the app and choose "Bacon" + "Tomato", I can see pending backups using `dumpsys backup`. So I force run it (`bgmr run` => pendings disappear) and uninstall the app.

When I restore it, logcat tells me "No restore data available" and of course, the settings aren't displayed with the correct info.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong ?

Comment: Please see this tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282936/android-backup-restore-how-to-backup-an-internal-database

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same response, and the previous comment didn't appear to help on this? Did you solve this? How did you do it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've had to just skip that functionnality for now. If you ever figure it out, do let me know !

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall the app the backup data got removed. Lookup logs for

```
BackupManagerService: Removing backed-up knowledge of <app package>
```

Seems that backup/restore process can vary from manufacturer and device. [Testing Backup and Restore](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup.html) document can simple work by uninstalling and installing using a nexus device, but I would not expect the same behavior and consistency on every device.

See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13648673/1598308

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error, only years later. It's probably because you are using Google Transport instead of LocalTransport. Google imposes a rate limit of 24 hours for every backup, so it's trying to create a backup, but it doesn't, and the restore fails.

1. Run **adb shell bmgr list transports** to see the transports.
2. Run **adb shell bmgr transport android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport** to change the transport to Local.