# How to backup and restore application database using android backup service?

Tags: android, sqlite

Could any body is having an idea how to do the backup and restoring of the Application's database data?

Comment: Please don't repeat questions.  If you don't like the answers you got before, then say so in that question,  If you have a different question, start a new one.  Repeating questions just clutters SO and is not a good thing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741185/how-to-do-the-backup-and-restoring-of-the-applications-database-data

Comment: No dude... Actually am not getting the rit solution... So only i have formed a new one....