# Android restore backup from database file on sdcard

Tags: android, android-sqlite, database-backups, database-restore

There are a few questions here on stackoverflow where people use BackupAgents to synchronize the apps data with googles cloud (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282936/android-backup-restore-how-to-backup-an-internal-database)). In my specific case the requirements are much more restrictive due to the nature of the more or less sensitive data. Everything must only be stored on the device itself and the app must not connect to the internet.

The main Activity contains a ViewPager which hosts a few ListFragments. Each ListFragment has its own Loader which swaps the cursor in a SimpleCursorAdapter class.

Before both backing up and restoring the database I destroy the loaders with:

```
getLoaderManager().destroy(LOADER_ID);
```

My backup function is similar to this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502223/backup-restore-sqlite-db-in-android?lq=1):

```
final String inFileName = "/data/data/<your.app.package>/databases/foo.db";
File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/database_copy.db";

// Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

// Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

// Close the streams
output.flush();
output.close();
fis.close();
```

The restore function is similar in that it copies the database from the sdcard back into the internal app folder, stops the loaders and overwrites the database file.

```
public static void restore(Context context) throws IOException {

    if (externalStorageIsWriteable()) {

        // getBackupDir() is a path to the folder on the sdcard
        File fileBackup = new File(getBackupDir(), WineSQLiteHelper.DB_NAME);

        if (!fileBackup.exists()) {
            throw new IOException("File not found");
        }

        File importFile = getImportDatabase();

        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(fileBackup, importFile);
            MySQLiteHelper dbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(context);
            dbHelper.close();
            dbHelper = null;

            File file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/"
                 + PACKAGE + "/databases/" + WineSQLiteHelper.DB_NAME);
            FileUtils.copyFile(importFile, file);

            // Remove temporary import file.
            importFile.delete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    } else {
        throw new IOException("External Storage not writeable");
    }
}
```

But somehow the MainActivity gets recreated after I've overwritten the database file and I recieve a few

```
SQLiteException: no such column
```

My guess is that perhaps there are still open connections to the database, but I'm not sure about that since this is the first time I have to work with databases this closely.

1. How to properly close all database connections of a ContentProvider? I can't find anything in the documentation about this. And is this necessary?
2. How do I properly restore the database?

Comment: If you think that you database is still open,please consider using database instance in a singleton pattern. SQLite database is supposed to be used that way. Here's an example http://db.tt/z7bvFkVJ take a look into HistoryDBSQLiteHelper.getInstance()

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have a ContentProvider sitting above the SQLiteHelper. There seems to be no way to access it via 'context.getContentResolver()'

Comment: Can you please explain more what do you mean by you cannot access it via 'context.getContentResolver()'?

Comment: ContentProviders classes are not instantiated directly. The system does this for you and gives you the ContentResolver interface to speak to ContentProviders. Basically I don't have a direct reference to my ContentProvider.