# Anonymize database and backup it

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Once I needed to make option to backup sqlite database, so I did it more or less like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13504743/6811048
Now because of GDPR I wanted to allow to my users to anonymizing database before backup(they want this option). So I tried to exec 'Update' on db, but it is not a feasible idea. I got db on phone which has no correct data.

Now how I can, in simple way, to achieve anonymous database as file but not to change original one?

I add that I have singleton as SQLProvider which create one instance of db.

Comment: What exactly in the GDPR made you take this action? Is it just fear of the big fines?

Comment: @John My clients want this option

Comment: Your clients won't be holding the data (as it is stored) on your users' phones and it is none of the GDPR's business.

Comment: @John can we focus on solving the problem?

Comment: Just remove the personal data. This is not a coding question.

Comment: If you're not personally collecting Sqlite database data, then you have no information yourself to protect as its all on the external devices. As long as you document that and tell users how to delete their own data, then aren't you fine on GDPR terms?

Answer (score 0):

> Now how I can, in simple way, to achieve anonymous database as file but not to change original one?

There is no simple way.  You need to:

1. analyze the database schema to identify all of the tables or fields that contain personally identified or identifying information,
2. design an alternative schema that removes or replaces the above in a way that makes it impossible to identify the person described by the data, and
3. implement a converter that will transform the data.

I am not aware of any automated tools that will do the above.

Comment: Ok, so I have no choice. I'll make external app which do what I want

Comment: Correct.  No choice.