# Flutter not clearing data even after installing / uninstalling app

Tags: flutter

I made a small mobile app using flutter. When using it, it saves data locally into the Sqlite database.
When I uninstall it , the database seems to get deleted as well, so next time I install the app again, the data is gone.
Any ideas how to leave the database file in the phone even the app is deleted?
Thank you.

Comment: did you find an answer for this question? I am currently having the same question like yours

Answer (score 7):

This issue exists if your device is Android 6 (API level 23)  and above, where android supports automatic backup, which means data will be stored in the device even if you uninstall the application.

**For Android:**

To get rid of this, go to the AndroidManifest file and add

```
<application 
     android:allowBackup="false"
     android:fullBackupOnly="false"
     //...
   />
```

**For iOS:**
refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57937650/5106574

Comment: actually the answer should be the reverse, the user wants to keep the file and not get rid of it

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to do this in iOS but for Android there is a way.

Apps that target Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher automatically participate in Auto Backup.

In your app manifest file, set the boolean value `android:allowBackup` to enable or disable backup.

The default value is `true`.

```
    <manifest ... >
        ...
        <application android:allowBackup="true" ... >
            ...
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

> The restore operation occurs after the APK is installed, but before the app is available to be launched by the user.

You can check out more information over [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html):

Answer (score -1):

I think the best  way to take backup, save db as a txt file, and set your file in somewhere  disk device . 
[Reading_Writing_file](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files)

OR create new db as a backup db 
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502223/backup-restore-sqlite-db-in-android)