# Flutter iOS delete cache when reinstall or update the app

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

I developed an app on Flutter. There is registration on the app.

When I install the app on iOS Phone. I logged in on the app, then I directly deleted the app from the iPhone for the test. Then I reinstall the app to the same phone. But app shows that I already logged in even though I am not logged on the second installation.

I think the phone is caching the first-time login and even if I delete the app, the cache is not deleting. Could it be the case?

I want to delete all data when the app is deleted or updated.

P.S. There is no such kind of problem on Android. When I delete the app from Android phone, everything is deleted and after reinstalling it, I need to log in.

Comment: Are you using a package that uses the keychain to store the login?

Comment: I used ```flutter_secure_storage``` for storing token and ```shared_preferences``` for storing user data

Comment: I've faced the same problem on Android, I'm using hive & hive_flutter packages to store user data. @MaksatMeredow Have you found the solution?

Comment: @Kelidon No, I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is duplicated from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933021/flutter-how-do-i-delete-fluttersecurestorage-items-during-install-uninstall/57937650#57937650).

Thanks to `shared_preferences` you can exploit `NSUserDefaults`, which is deleted every time you uninstall the app, to check if the app is running for the first time.