# Flutter - delete all data when uninstalling by the user (iOS /Android)

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Is there a possibility for iOS & Android to delete all data when uninstalling the mobile application? his does not mean the debug version of a developer on a test device. This scenario should be ensured.

Comment: Starting with Android 11 and all other iOS versions, all the data is deleted when the user uninstalls an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS deletes all the data related to your app when the user uninstalls the app.

However, things are little different in Android. Before Android 11, you could have saved the data in device external storage which isn't deleted after uninstalling the app although the internal storage data (`Android` > `data` > `com.xxx`) is deleted.

But with Android 11, you don't need to worry about the external storage data anymore because you have no access to it and hence you can't store anything there. So, you're only left with the internal storage.

*So, all the data will be deleted automatically when the user uninstalls the app.*

Comment: Is there anything to backup the claim that iOS deletes all app data when uninstalling the app? Because there seems to be at least an asterisk as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933021) this does not seem to apply universally.

Answer (score 2):

**This is done by the OS**(Android/iOS) as all the data is deleted when the **app** is uninstalled.

In addition to this, you should check `android:allowBackup` and `android:fullBackupContent` options in your manifest file. Check more info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup)

If you want to also delete some files that we store in a folder on the sd card? **You will not be able to**, since those files are no longer your app files but just some files that the app uses and you can consider storing them in a different way.

Comment: With Android 11.0, you no longer have access to the external storage.

Comment: You do not have access as you had before but you still have access to store files. You are just forced to place them in the right folder.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the first line clearly.