# Android app updating upgrading debugging

Tags: android, debugging, upgrade, sqliteopenhelper

**When updating/upgrading an android app, you have to:**

- update the versions in the manifest
- update the SQLiteOpenHelper's OnUpgrade Method
- that's it as far as I know

*I get stuck when I want to debug the upgrade itself*

**The reason for my problem and my attempts:**

- my database has changed, and for some reason my onUpgrade doesn't
  help and I need to debug it
- the package has been signed and therefore I have to sign it before I can override the existing version of the app
- if I sign it and install it over the other app, it crashes immediately, but then I cannot debug it, because it is installed straight from the apk, and not from eclipse debugging console

**The Issue:**

- I get the famous "Re-installation failed due to different application
  signatures" error.

**My little research:**

- this has been covered in many posts here (at least 10 that I've read)
- most of them offered to remove the app, but that will cause the database to be deleted also, and that defeats the point
- some of them offered to refer to a file in %USER_HOME%/.android/ called debug.keystore
- others referred to what you can do with the adb
- and the only close answer to what I wanted was debugging under devices tab in eclipse, but I couldn't

Answer (score 0):

If you still have access to the old version of the application source code add some dev menu options to backup/restore the database.  Sign with your release key and then use the app to backup the database.

Then add the same code to your new app you are developing, you will be able to restore the database and then try the upgrade process using your debug key.  It just means you'll have to temporarily comment out the upgrade process and anything that fails because of it until you have a working old version of your database with the new app in debug.

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282936/android-backup-restore-how-to-backup-an-internal-database) to the method I used to to backup databases.

Comment: OK first of all thank you, second of all I already have a backup function in my app (so that's good), but unfortunately couldn't find a decent restoration example, also was hoping that someone would offer something I can do with the IDE to debug it, because this workaround is a bit of a stretch