# retrieve sqlite table when debugging app in phone

Tags: android, sqlite

as per question, I know if I run my app on an emulator, I can retrieve a copy of the generated sqlite table by just going to the /bin folder. But how can I do the same, if I run my app on my device?

edit: it seems I was right on the part that I can retrieve the sqlite table by going to the /bin folder, only if I am using Eclipse. But currently I'm using Android Studio... so anyone here knows how to retrieve the generated sqlite table?

Comment: you need to root your device for accessing database

Comment: @MHP ouch that's going to be a problem for me than.. anyway you have any idea on how to retrieve generated sqlite tables if I use Android Studio?

Comment: you can do it after app installed and database created by some code

Comment: yup @MHP my app was already installed and database was already created.. the problem is I don't know how can I copy the generated database to somewhere else. I can do this without any problem when I use eclipse, but on Android Studio, I don't know where's the physical location Android Studio puts the generated sqlite database..

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282936/android-backup-restore-how-to-backup-an-internal-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve your sqlite-databases even if your device isn't rooted. Here's how:

### Step 1 - Open adb command prompt

Go to your `android-sdk` folder --> `platform-tools` and open the command prompt.

### Step 2 - Backup

Enter the following line in your command prompt:

> adb backup -f my_backup.ab -noapk com.mypackage.name

Unlock your device and you should see something like this:

[image: adb backup screenshot]

Confirm the backup-operation without entering a password

***Note:*** *This will only work on devices running Android 4.0 and above*

### Step 3 - Unpacking the backup

Now you should see a file called `my_backup.ab` in your `platform-tools` folder. That's a compressed and encrypted backup file of android which we need to extract now.
Download the following tool called [Android Backup Extractor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/).

Now extract the `*.zip` file of the Android Backup Extractor and copy your `*.ab` file into this directory. And run the following command:

> java -jar abe.jar unpack my_backup.ab my_backup.tar

Afterwards a new archive should appear called **my_backup.tar**. Open it an browse to the `/db/` directory. There you'll see all of your databases. **Done!**