# Location of my package while USB debugging in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, usb-debugging

I searched a lot in DDMS all folders but can not find the location of my package folder in file manager. I have search it into the `storage/sdcard0` but there also my package is not present.

[image]

take a look I uploaded photo. Is there any special setting from mobile ? 
**My phone android version 4.4.2**

please help me to find.

**UPDATE**

I gone through this steps.

And I reach to My database folder .Now What to do.

```
adb shell
run-as com.mypackage
ls
cd databases
ls
```

Now After this what to do.

[image]

Comment: Do you look for a special file in your app-directory like the *SharedPreferences* or *Databases*?

Comment: I am looking for databases

Comment: Are you sure it is working in Android Studio.

Answer (score 3):

As you are looking for the database.
I used to copy the database file to any other location after updating it. ( in my code)
Then I use any sqlite viewer over phone or over PC to view it.

Comment: Wow That's Good Idea My Friend.

Comment: what about files and shared preferences.

Answer (score 2):

I Think you need a rooted device 
as far as I know the files on sdcard/Android/data are not the primary files for the packages, those are only extra files (most probably not critical and large files) which are saved on the external storage which is the sdcard.

main package files are saved on the internal storage.

I think you can try this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html
you can change the location of app installation.

Br,

Comment: I dont have have sdcard install in my phone so default will be the phone storage

Comment: The phone storage is the `/sdcard` folder. The storage of an external sdcard would be in `/external_sd`.

Comment: @Hussein I Update my Question please take a look

Answer (score 2):

You can't see the files in DDMS, but you can get a list of the location of all the files using the command:

```
adb shell pm list packages -f
```

(you can also add an optional extra parameter to restrict the files listed to be those that match your extra parameter).

Once you have the location of the file, you can then issue a command like

```
adb pull /system/app/GoogleEarth.apk
```

to actually get the file off the device and on to your PC.

None of this requires a rooted device.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're looking for the database of your application: Unfortunately there's no way to access the `/data/data/your.package.name/databases` through *DDMS* on an unrooted device, as [Hussein Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353515/hussein-ali) pointed out correctly. (By the way: The app-data (**shared prefs, databases**) will reside there no matter of the install-location)

Something like this won't work neither because of `Permission denied`.

> adb pull /data/data/your.package.name/databases/db.sl3

Luckily ICS (Android 4.0) introducted the ability to backup your application-data. That's a possible way to copy your database from your unrooted device to your PC. Please see [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532084/retrieve-sqlite-table-when-debugging-app-in-phone/25544266#25544266) in order to see what you need to do.

Comment: this is long process not feasible solution. Any other solution.

Comment: There's no other solution unless you root your device or use an emulator.

Comment: I am planning to root but there is no successful root steps of my micromax unite 2.

Comment: I go through this stps and I see my databases folder as well as my database but can not read it.

Comment: Well I suggested you some other steps but never mind. At this you can't do anything since there's nothing like a `sqlite3-viewer` on your Android device. Furthermore you can't copy the database to your `sdcard` for security reason.

Comment: Ok I'll keep this thing in mind. Thanks for help buddy.

Answer (score 1):

copy the database file to your SD card so you'll be able to use `adb pull` and get the database to your PC (You can't pull files from private folders such as `/data/data/...`).

I recommend using `SQLite Expert` to browse the DB on your desktop:
http://www.sqliteexpert.com/

Also, If you still want to use `sqlite3` on your device, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7878236/624109

Comment: But what about other data like filesd and shared_pref.

Comment: What about them? `shared_prefs` is a folder that contains xml files with your shared preferences and `files` contains your internal/private files of the app (Which by looking at the screenshot provided in the question, you have none). Read more on files at the following links http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)

Answer (score 1):

phone storage is treated as external storage in location "sdcard" where you havn't saved anything so nothing(package named folder) is created... your package will be in app's "private storage" that's in root "data/data/pkg_name" folder accessible only on rooted device.

Comment: But brother My device is not rooted.

Comment: why you need to explore your package folder?

Comment: for see my database, files, shared prefs, cache

Comment: you can use emulator for testing...these values are stored in app's private storage. And you cannot explore them for security reasons.

Comment: if you still need it...search for how to back up your app and explore *.ab(android backup file) on your system.

Comment: Ok I will look at this.