# How to get the all the previously stored data from sqlite from ionic1

Tags: android, sqlite, ionic-framework

I have created an application which stores data locally in sqlite and when internet available update to server and update the response in local sqlite but some errors make my data in sqlite to be null I would like to revert the sqlite db back to similar way.I would like to know is it possible to revert the database in sqlite back to the one which i have started.If so can anyone tell me what is the solution for it?

Comment: U can try backing up sqlite before trying and if something nasty happens use that backup and reload data , refer here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282936/android-backup-restore-how-to-backup-an-internal-database